# After changing classes on a link, why doesn't a click function tied to the new class fire?

Tags: jquery

I have a link that, when clicked, does stuff, then swaps the class for something else.

I would expect to be able to interact with that new class just as I did with the first, but I seem to be unable to do so. Why is this, and what should I do?

http://jsfiddle.net/3uJEa/

HTML:

```
<a class="state-one" href="javascript:void(0);">What is the capital of Assyria?</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.state-one').click(function() {
    $(this).html("Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government!");
    $(this).addClass("state-two").removeClass("state-one");
});

$('.state-two').click(function() {
    $(this).html("What is the capital of Assyria?");
    $(this).addClass("state-one").removeClass("state-two");
});
```

Comment: Because event binding done this way happens only for elements found at the time the code is executed. Go check the jQuery docs on `.on` for the way to use it to replace `.live`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(...).click(...)` binds a handler to the *element*. Changing an attribute of the element doesn't change what handlers are bound to it. You're looking for event delegation with [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

http://jsfiddle.net/RaSrm/

```
$(document).on('click', '.state-one', function() {
    $(this).html("Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government!");
    $(this).addClass("state-two").removeClass("state-one");
});

$(document).on('click', '.state-two', function() {
    $(this).html("What is the capital of Assyria?");
    $(this).addClass("state-one").removeClass("state-two");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and helpful answer as well as the link to the docs! Guess I have a new concept to learn :)